# Change from static HTML file to meta tag for Google Webmaster verification

Tags: search, google-search-console

I started verifying the server by putting a couple of static HTMLs in place. Then I noticed that Google wants you to keep these files in place. I didn't want to keep the static HTMLs in, so I want to switch to an *alternative* verification mechanism, and include the meta tags on the home page.

Unfortunately, once your site is verified, you never seem to be able to change to an alternative way of verification. I tried removing the HTML pages. No luck whatsoever. Google still considers the site to be 'verified'.

Does anybody know how to undo this? All I want to do is switch to the meta tag based method of site ownership verification.

Comment: Not sure you can re-verify. Just go to your sites page, under the "Manage Site" drop-down, select "Delete Site".  You should be able to re-add the site using the alternate verification.

Comment: I tried this: https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=140369, but the 'Verified' link they are talking about isn't there.

Comment: By the way, deleting the site and adding it again isn't helping. It remembered that it verified the site in the past. :(

Comment: Click on "Manage Site" -> "Add Remove Owners" -> "Unverify" on the far right of your username.  Just tested this with one of my domains. After this, I was able to re-add my site and offered to verify again.

Comment: If you use WordPress CMS then you can use the plugin name "Google verification".

Comment: You could also verify the site on someone elses account or a dummy account which will then force you to need to verify it again on your current account before you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure I can close this question, jscott was right:

> Click on "Manage Site" -> "Add Remove Owners" -> "Unverify" on the far
>   right of your username. Just tested this with one of my domains. After
>   this, I was able to re-add my site and offered to verify again.